# H&FJ fonts from typography.com look awful on iOS

Tags: ios, css, font-face

I'm using the cloud-based Gotham Screensmart on a website I'm building. It looks fine on desktop browsers, but looks like this on iOS Safari...

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening and what I can do to sort it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out this is because HF&J split their fonts into 2 when delivering them via the cloud.

I had only added one font to my CSS instead of 2.

`font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B"`

Comment: Wow. Didn't realise that the fonts were split. Now I get the A & B thing! Thanks.